# Deleted /lib/modules/<kernel version> by mistake. How to recover?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, rm, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted my `/lib/modules/<kernel version directory>`.

Here's the full output of `sudo rm -rfv /lib/modules/4.14.98+` : [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/bj9ei0Sw)

Is there a way to restore the modules keeping the system online?

It is a raspberry pi sitting on an internal network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dpkg --search /lib/modules/<kernel version directory>` to find what packages this directory (and inside) belong to, then use `apt-get --reinstall install <list from before>` to reinstall any affected package missing, thus restoring missing content.

In one liner this should be (remove the `-d` once sure of the effect):

```
apt-get -d --reinstall install $(dpkg -S /lib/modules/4.14.98+ | tr ',:' '\n\n' | head -n -1)
```

As I don't know well if RPi follows the usual kernel installation method (`depmod` etc.) you should then check that after this you can modprobe any random module (eg: the `dummy` module) not already loaded before considering everything is fine.

PS: in case of additional *[dkms](https://manpages.debian.org/dkms/dkms.8)* modules, above won't track it, but you can then continue the "restoration" with `dkms status` to get a list and `dkms install module/module-version -k 4.14.98+` to put back what's missing etc.